# Logic Error in Code - Not Outputting Properly

Tags: java, logic

My task was to create a program that, when run, would output the number of years invested (which is input by the user), the amount the user invests (also input by the user), the interest on that investment (user inputted), and the overall total at the end of the year. The next year, it is assumed that the user invests the same amount again, which adds to the total. For example:
If the user invests $200.00, at 2% interest, for 4 years, print out a table showing their financial gain.
So, 200 + 4% of 200 = Total
The next year, the user invests $200 more dollars. 
So, then the total for the next year would be the Total (from the previous year) * 4% of the new total.
This pattern continues for a maximum of fifteen years.

I am having problems with the "investmentAmount" specifically. It is not printing correctly.
Here is my entire code:
     **EDITED**

```
   double investmentAmount; //the amount the user chooses to invest, expressed as a double
   investmentAmount = Double.parseDouble(InputInvestmentAmount);
   double Interest; // amount of interest in percent, expressed as a double
   Interest = Double.parseDouble(InputInterest);
   double YearsInvested; //the total years (under 15) the user wants to invest, expressed as a double
   YearsInvested = Double.parseDouble(InputYearsInvested);
   double Zero = 0; //a starting point for the year
   double Total;
    System.out.println("Years Invested \t\tAmount in Account\t\tInterest\t\tTotal");
   if (YearsInvested >=16)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I am sorry. Please make sure that you are investing your money for "
               + "less than 16 years.", "Compound Investing Calculator",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
   do {
       Zero++; //the year

        Interest = (investmentAmount*(Interest/100));
        Total = investmentAmount+Interest;
       System.out.format("%5.2f%32f%28f%25f%n",Zero,investmentAmount,Interest,Total);

   }
   while (YearsInvested <= 15 && Zero<=YearsInvested-1);
```

The output is currently:

```
Years Invested      Amount in Account       Interest        Total
 1.00                      408.000000                    8.000000               408.000000
 2.00                      848.640000                   32.640000               848.640000
 3.00                     1974.276096                  276.996096              1974.276096
 4.00                     9417.219902                 5468.667710              9417.219902
 5.00                   533830.903792               514996.463987            533830.903792
 6.00               2750277940.006539           2749210278.198955        2750277940.006539
```

Now, I am just dealing with a small problem. I need the "amount in Account" to not equal the Total. Any suggestions? I am sure it is a small problem...

Comment: Is everything in `showInputDialog`'s necessary to understand the code? That's taking away from the problem and reducing readability...

Comment: I was wondering that, I edited out the unnecessary parts.

Comment: Regarding `Interest = (investmentAmount*=(Interest/100));`, have you tried to break this up into two lines? The way it is written seems al little off.

Comment: try changing `Interest = (investmentAmount*=(Interest/100))` to `Interest = (investmentAmount * (Interest / 100))`

Comment: Other than that, I can't really see anythigng that is wrong with the code :/

Comment: @AardenHartle If you have a new question, please ask a new question :) That is, tf the previous problem was solved, then accept an answer that answered that question. I would be happy to help you with a different question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main while-loop.

```
 Interest = (investmentAmount*=(Interest/100));
```

, this should be broken up into two lines, such as:

```
 investmentAmount = (Interest/100);
 Interest = investmentAmount*(Interest/100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You kept overwriting your old variables. Keep in mind once you overwrite a variable it won't reset.

```
     String InputInvestmentAmount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hello, and welcome to Compound Investing.\nThis programme will print out a titled table, that will show you \nthe amount of yearly investment, for a period up to 15 years."
    + "\nPlease enter a Yearly Investment Amount ($) below.","Compound Investing Calculator",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    String InputInterest = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input the interest rate in percent (%) below.","Compound Investing Calculator",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   String InputYearsInvested = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Lastly, please enter the number of years for the investment. "
           + "No numbers higher than 15, please.","Compound Investing Calculator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   double investmentAmount; //the amount the user chooses to invest, expressed as a double
   investmentAmount = Double.parseDouble(InputInvestmentAmount);
   double Interest; // amount of interest in percent, expressed as a double
   Interest = Double.parseDouble(InputInterest);
   double YearsInvested; //the total years (under 15) the user wants to invest, expressed as a double
   YearsInvested = Double.parseDouble(InputYearsInvested);
   double Zero = 0; //a starting point for the year
   double Total;
    System.out.println("Years Invested \t\tAmount in Account\t\tInterest\t\tTotal");
   if (YearsInvested >=16)
   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"I am sorry. Please make sure that you are investing your money for "
               + "less than 16 years.", "Compound Investing Calculator",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
   double IntrestMoney;
   do {
       Zero++; //the year

        IntrestMoney = investmentAmount*(Interest/100);
        Total = investmentAmount+IntrestMoney;

       System.out.format("%5.2f%32f%28f%25f%n",Zero,investmentAmount,Interest,Total);
       investmentAmount=Total;
   }
   while (YearsInvested <= 15 && Zero<=YearsInvested-1); 

 }
```

After running the code you will get this output:

```
Years Invested      Amount in Account       Interest        Total
 1.00                      200.000000                   10.000000               220.000000
 2.00                      220.000000                   10.000000               242.000000
 3.00                      242.000000                   10.000000               266.200000
 4.00                      266.200000                   10.000000               292.820000
 5.00                      292.820000                   10.000000               322.102000
```